# VBA Search Two Ranges and Execute action

Tags: vba, excel

I tried searching for some potential answers to this question but I suppose my issue is too specific and I can't apply solutions I found.

[image: Source Example]

With above source I need to scan Column A and identify all John Doe's and afterwards for all John Doe I need to scan corresponding cells in Column B and if there is Date in any of them take the newest date and paste it into all corresponding cells.

So expected result would be:

[image: Expected Result]

Any hints on how to achieve this? I'm afraid my VBA skills are too weak.

Comment: Even with weak skills you can achieve a lot with VBA. Try something, looping through Excel and saving the values in variables. Then share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2013 and prior versions, this can be achieved without macros with an array formula. To use an array formula, type the formula in a cell (without `{` and `}`), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May I propose simple formula solution to your problem? if you have your email name in column `A` , and Dates in column `B`, enter this formula `=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$100,$A$2:$A$100,A2)` in cell `B2` and drag it to the bottom. You should get this result. Adjust range inside formula to your needs.

[image]

Comment: ``MAXIFS()`` was introduced with Excel 2016, I believe. In prior versions, you need an array formula like ``{=MAX(IF(criteria_range=criteria,value_range))}``

Comment: Thanks Kresimir - unfortunately I'm running Excel 2013 (Should have specified that - apologies) so your suggestion does not work.

Frank - since I'll have  to admit I'm not that familiar with that functionality - what would the Criteria_range; Criteria_value and value_range be in my case?

Comment: Try @Frank Seifert solution, that should work on Excel 2013 and prior.